# Odoo workers with apache

Tags: apache, nginx, multiprocessing, odoo

Why odoo prefers Nginx over Apache server?

Apache and ngnix both provides the same features for reverse proxy and enabling workers for multi processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo is working on both provider you can see in this link

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/deploy.html

> To achieve such a thing, you’ll need to deploy a reverse proxy in front of Odoo, like nginx or apache.

you will choose any provider odoo will works.

Thanks